# virtual env in django

Tags: python, django, windows

While I was trying to execute the mkvirtualenv command on the command prompt, I was getting this error:
'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

python 3.10
windows 11

Expecting to create a virtual env

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install `virtualenvwrapper`

```
$ sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

---

However I whilst I'm here I'd love to offer an alternative. In modern python we  also have `venv` and performs the same thing.

Create a new env:

```
$ py -m venv env/
```

This creates a new `env/` directory using the package (`-m` module) `venv`.
Now you can activate it at will:

windows:

```
> env\Scripts\activate
```

linux

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

From then the console `python` will be this virtual env copy.

Answer (score 0):

I have been there before. You just do this when your making the enviroment. sometimes you just do activate. Other times you'll just have to do activate.bat to open the file.

Create the environment

```
py -m venv env
```

Go to the directory

```
cd venv/scripts
```

Activate the environment

```
activate or activate.bat
```